# Typing indicator and time stamp implementation in android studio

Tags: java, android, chat

I'm doing a project in android studio. But I'm stuck while implementing typing indicator and time stamp in the chat app. I'm very new to android studio. Please be simple and try to be specific with the codes that I need to add here in my application. I have already created the chat bubble and the UI for the chat. Pl. help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend its a really ambiguous question, but in general you need to make a callback function on the text-field when the text is changed you send the other guy notification of typing. something like this:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
            int count, int after) {
            lengthBeforeType = mEditText.getText().toString().length();

        }
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, 
            int before, final int count) {
            lengthAfterType = mEditText.getText().toString().length();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        if((lengthAfterType-lengthBeforeType)<0){
                            session.stopTyping();
                        }else{
                            session.typing();
                        }
                    } catch (OmegleException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```